# Symfony 2 prod environment Deprecated call

Tags: symfony, deprecated

I just finished the [Symblog](http://tutorial.symblog.co.uk/) tutorial for symfony. Everything works just fine except when I try running the project on the production environment. On the blog page the following error message appears on the top of the page and on top of the comment section: `Deprecated: getEntityManager is deprecated since Symfony 2.1. Use getManager instead in F:\xampp\htdocs\php\symblog\vendor\doctrine\doctrine-bundle\Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\Registry.php on line 71`
I am wondering why because I used the same version (symfony 2.3.10) for other projects and in these I have never seen this message. So what should I do?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should replace your code to use `getManager()` method instead of `getEntityManager()` or just change your error_reporting PHP setting (take a look at the below snippet).

The reason of not showing other depreciation messages in other project is different error reporting configuration (probably somwthing similar to the following - deprecated warnings will not be reported):

```
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_DEPRECATED);
```

Comment: I found out the problem in the dev environment. I used `getEntityManager()` in a controller. What confused me was that the error points to a file in symfony that I never touched. But now it's working. Thanks.

Comment: @Kable this is why we always should have all errors/warnings visible in the development environment :) Glad to help.

Comment: It is being thrown from an internal function/file, but that function is being called from external code. If you look at the error-log (from apache, or other app server), you'll see where it was called from.